# Oracle Advanced Queueing with .Net

Tags: .net, oracle

Somebody knows how to implement Oracle Advance Queue from C# using PL/SSQL and ODP.NET? 
I can't find a single example or resource with concrete examples in C# or VB.NET. 
Ideally I would like some examples on how the enqueue and dequeue messages with simple types (XMl/string).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can't help you with the best practices, but I can help you with a UDT Queue. Before you deal with the queue, you need to generate custom types from the database into your C# project. Assuming you have Visual Studio and ODP.NET installed, you simply need to connect to the database through the Server Explorer, locate your UDTs, right click and choose "Generate Custom Class..." These classes map directly to your UDTs and are used to store the Dequeued information.

Here is an example of the code you would use to enqueue a message:

```
private void main(string[] args)
{
    string _connstring = "Data Source=host/DB;User
    Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD1;";

        OracleConnection _connObj = new OracleConnection(_connstring);

        // Create a new queue object
        OracleAQQueue _queueObj = new OracleAQQueue("UDT_NAME", _connObj);

        _connObj.Open();

        OracleTransaction _txn = _connObj.BeginTransaction();

        // Set the payload type to your UDT
        _queueObj.MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt;
        _queueObj.UdtTypeName = "UDT_NAME";

        // Create a new message object
        OracleAQMessage _msg = new OracleAQMessage();

        // Create an instance of JobClass and pass it in as the payload for the
        // message
        UDT_CUSTOM_CLASS _custClass = new UDT_CUSTOM_CLASS();
        // Load up all of the properties of custClass
        custClass.CustString = "Custom String";
        custClass.CustInt = 5;

        _msg.Payload = custClass;

        // Enqueue the message
        _queueObj.EnqueueOptions.Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.OnCommit;
        _queueObj.Enqueue(_msg);

        _txn.Commit();
        _queueObj.Dispose();
        _connObj.Close();
        _connObj.Dispose();
        _connObj = null;
}
```

It's a similar process to dequeue:

```
private void main(string[] args)
{
    string _connstring = "Data Source=host/DB;User
    Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD1;";

    OracleConnection _connObj = new OracleConnection(_connstring);

    // Create a new queue object
    OracleAQQueue _queueObj = new OracleAQQueue("UDT_NAME", _connObj);

    // Set the payload type to your UDT
    _queueObj.MessageType = OracleAQMessageType.Udt;
    _queueObj.UdtTypeName = "UDT_NAME";

    _connObj.Open();

    OracleTransaction _txn = _connObj.BeginTransaction();

    // Dequeue the message.
    _queueObj.DequeueOptions.Visibility = OracleAQVisibilityMode.OnCommit;
    _queueObj.DequeueOptions.Wait = 10;
    OracleAQMessage _deqMsg = _queueObj.Dequeue();

    UDT_CUSTOM_CLASS data = (UDT_CUSTOM_CLASS)_deqMsg.Payload;

    // At this point, you have the data and can do whatever you need to do with it

    _txn.Commit();
    _queueObj.Dispose();
    _connObj.Close();
    _connObj.Dispose();
    _connObj = null;

}
```

That's a "simple" example. I pulled most of that out of Pro ODP.NET for Oracle Database 11g by Ed Zehoo. It's an excellent book and I strongly recommend it to help you gain a better understanding of the ins and outs of all things OPD.NET. You can buy the eBook here: http://apress.com/book/view/9781430228202. If you enter the coupon code MACWORLDOC, you can get the eBook for $21.00. That offer is only good for the eBook which comes in a password protected PDF format. I hope this helps!

Comment: In case anyone comes across this please be aware that the ODP.NET, Unmanaged driver is not supported on VS2019.  You will need to install VS2017 and 12.2 to get the data provider option in the server explorer.  Only then can you automatically generate the UDT class.  3 days wasted.  That's Oracle for you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the exact answer to this problem but here is what we did:

- First every .net application that need to listen on the ESB (ESB is build on AQ)  has to use his own local Oracle DB and dequeue messages from there.  The messages are propagated to the local queues.  This solves the potential scalability problem linked to keeping a DB connection open to recieve messages.
- Second we built our own AQ library that basicly encapsulate stored procedures. - this is not needed any more as Oracle has finaly released an the ODAC [11.1.0.7.20](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html) (with an ODP.NET  that supports AQ).  We use Oracle types as sort of DTO to define the message contracts.

Comment: The 2nd option is what I did to dequeue. Interesting to see they've added proper support in .NET via ODP.NET.

Answer (score 3):

I had a requirement where I had to enqueue/dequeue UDT messages to a queue. This post was really helpful. It has almost everything but creation of a "Oracle Custom Type" is missing. I thought its worth adding that code here so that the solution is complete.

To EnQueue/DeQueue in Oracle:

User with role "AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE" has to be created. In the example below, the "AQUSER" is created with that role.

```
PL Sql to EnQueue:

DECLARE
    queue_options       DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
    message_properties  DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
    message_id          RAW(16);
    my_message          AQUSER.USER_DEFINED_TYPE;
BEGIN
    my_message := AQUSER.USER_DEFINED_TYPE('XXX','YYY','ZZZ');
    DBMS_AQ.ENQUEUE(
        queue_name => 'AQUSER.QUEUE_NAME',
        enqueue_options => queue_options,
        message_properties => message_properties,
        payload => my_message,
        msgid => message_id);
    COMMIT;
END;
/ 

PL SQL to DeQueue

DECLARE
    queue_options       DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE_OPTIONS_T;
    message_properties  DBMS_AQ.MESSAGE_PROPERTIES_T;
    message_id          RAW(2000);
    my_message          AQUSER.USER_DEFINED_TYPE;
BEGIN
    DBMS_AQ.DEQUEUE(
        queue_name => 'AQUSER.QUEUE_NAME',
        dequeue_options => queue_options,
        message_properties => message_properties,
        payload => my_message,
        msgid => message_id );
    COMMIT;
END;
/

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

To create a Oracle Custom Type, you can use the following code:

    public class CustomMessageType : IOracleCustomType, INullable
    {

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("XXXXX")]
        public string XXXXX { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("YYYYY")]
        public string YYYYY { get; set; }

        [OracleObjectMappingAttribute("ZZZZZ")]
        public string ZZZZZ { get; set; }

        public void FromCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(XXXXX))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "XXXXX", XXXXX);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(YYYYY))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "YYYYY", YYYYY);
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ZZZZZ))
            {
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, "ZZZZZ", ZZZZZ);
            }
        }

        public void ToCustomObject(Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
        {
            XXXXX  = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "XXXXX");
            YYYYY = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "YYYYY");
            ZZZZZ = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, "ZZZZZ");
        }

        public bool IsNull { get; set; }

    }


    [OracleCustomTypeMappingAttribute("SCHEMA.CUSTOM_TYPE")]
    public class QueueMessageTypeFactory : IOracleCustomTypeFactory
    {
        public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
        {
            return new CustomMessageType();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can i get more details about this implementation like where are these stored procedures called

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nice example I found from Oracle.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-nov/o69net-099734.html

Code: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-nov/o69odt-131369.zip

Comment: The links are no longer working. Because of this, it's usually better to also paste the relevant parts in your answer along with the link, so the information doesn't become unavailable when the link stops working in the future.

Answer (score 0):

AQ has plsql interface via DBMS_AQ[adm]. All you need is run that packages from your environment and common AQ examples and setup. I don't think that there is anything special when you call those packages from c#.

Comment: Sorry but that I have to use PL/SQL and stored procedures is allready part of the question.  The problem is that when dequeuing messages many options are available e.g. the time-out of the connection.  Also UDT are used as parameter for the dequeue store proc - I don't know how to create UDT from .Net with 10G.  What I'm looking for are some examples of c# code and best practices (e.g. close the db connection or leave it open???)

Comment: Does any one have any example on this? I am also looking for this. ;)