# Oracle UDTs Custom type mapping for is not specified or is invalid

Tags: c#, oracle, object, types, user-defined-types

I got this error, "Custom type mapping for 'ClassXX' is not specified or is invalid.
Is it possible that my member value type is not correct to match db UDTs?

Here is my Code:

ClassXX

```
[OracleCustomTypeMapping("DB.T_OUTERTRAN")]
public class ClassXX: AOracleCustomObject<ClassXX>
{
    [OracleObjectMapping("OUTERSYSTEMCODE")]
    public int OuterSystemCode { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMapping("TRANSACTIONSOURCE")]
    public int TransactionSource { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMapping("TRANSACTIONTYPE")]
    public int TransactionType { get; set; }

    [OracleObjectMapping("AMOUNTCHANGE")]
    public decimal AmountChange { get; set; }
    [OracleObjectMapping("REFERENCENO")]
    public string ReferenceNo { get; set; }
    [OracleObjectMapping("REMARKS")]
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    [OracleObjectMapping("VENDORID")]
    public int VendorId { get; set; }
    [OracleObjectMapping("BUID")]
    public int BuId { get; set; }
    [OracleObjectMapping("USERCODE")]
    public string UserCode { get; set; }
    [OracleObjectMapping("ACCEPTNEGATIVEBALANCE")]
    public int AcceptNegativeBalance { get; set; }

    protected override ClassXX _getObjInstance()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

AOracleCustomObject:

```
public abstract class AOracleCustomObject<T> : INullable, IOracleCustomTypeFactory, IOracleCustomType
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public bool IsNull
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        T oracleObj = _getObjInstance();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var attrs = (OracleObjectMappingAttribute[])
                property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OracleObjectMappingAttribute), false);
            if (attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                string attrName = attrs[0].AttributeName;
                object value = property.GetValue(oracleObj, null);
                OracleUdt.SetValue(con, pUdt, attrName, value);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection con, IntPtr pUdt)
    {
        T oracleObj = _getObjInstance();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var attrs = (OracleObjectMappingAttribute[])
                property.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(OracleObjectMappingAttribute), false);
            if (attrs.Length > 0)
            {
                string attrName = attrs[0].AttributeName;
                Type ptype = property.PropertyType;
                object value = Convert.ChangeType(OracleUdt.GetValue(con, pUdt, attrName), ptype);
                property.SetValue(oracleObj, value, null);
            }
        }
    }

    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return (IOracleCustomType)_getObjInstance();
    }

    protected abstract T _getObjInstance();
}
```

UDTs:

```
    create or replace TYPE T_OUTERTRAN AS OBJECT 
( 
  OUTERSYSTEMCODE NUMBER(4,0),
  TRANSACTIONSOURCE NUMBER(4,0),
  TRANSACTIONTYPE   NUMBER(4,0),
  AMOUNTCHANGE NUMBER(26,6),  
  REFERENCENO   VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
  REMARKS   VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
  VENDORID  NUMBER(4,0),  
  BUID NUMBER(5,0),
  USERCODE  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  ACCEPTNEGATIVEBALANCE NUMBER(1,0)
);
```

The Exception log is

```
    Custom type mapping for 'ClassXX' is not specified or is invalid.
System.InvalidOperationException: Custom type mapping for 'ClassXX' is not specified or is invalid.
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Types.OracleUdt.GetUdtName(String customTypeName, String dataSource)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.SetUDTFromCustomObject(OracleConnection conn, IOracleCustomType customObj, Int32 i)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind_Collection(OracleConnection conn)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleParameter.PreBind(OracleConnection conn, IntPtr errCtx, Int32 arraySize)
   at Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: BTW, I do sure the user of db connection has privilege to execute the object type

Comment: How does the query look? I tested your code and it runs fine but the values are not mapped. Is the assembly containing the custom type accessible to load?

Comment: Hi, in fact, the query sql is PL/SQL, but it is really complicated.

I've confirmed that the class member and udt are the same, why the values can not be mapped?

Sorry, I don't really understand your seconds question, all these code are in a dll, and another project reference to the dll, call its method.

Comment: The second question meant if the assembly is statically referenced, otherwise it needs to be loaded manually. When I used your implementation of the custom type the values were just default values for the respected types.

Answer (score 4):

I tried simple roundtrip and everything seems to work fine.

```
void Main()
{
    using (var connection = new OracleConnection("DATA SOURCE=HQ_PDB_TCP;PASSWORD=oracle;USER ID=HUSQVIK"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "DECLARE i SYS.ODCICOST := :p; BEGIN :p := SYS.ODCICOST(i.CPUCOST + 1, i.IOCOST + 1, i.NETWORKCOST + 1, i.INDEXCOSTINFO || 'Dummy'); END;";
            command.BindByName = true;

            var parameter = command.CreateParameter();
            parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
            parameter.ParameterName = "p";
            parameter.OracleDbType = OracleDbType.Object;
            parameter.UdtTypeName = "SYS.ODCICOST";
            parameter.Value = new OdciCost { CPUCOST = 123, INDEXCOSTINFO = "DUMMY", IOCOST = 456, NETWORKCOST = 789 };
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var odciCost = (OdciCost)parameter.Value;
            Console.WriteLine($"CPUCOST={odciCost.CPUCOST}; IOCOST={odciCost.IOCOST}; NETWORKCOST={odciCost.NETWORKCOST}; INDEXCOSTINFO={odciCost.INDEXCOSTINFO}");
        }
    }
}

[OracleCustomTypeMapping("SYS.ODCICOST")]
public class OdciCost : IOracleCustomType, IOracleCustomTypeFactory, INullable
{
    private bool _isNull;
    [OracleObjectMapping("CPUCOST")]
    public decimal CPUCOST;
    [OracleObjectMapping("INDEXCOSTINFO")]
    public string INDEXCOSTINFO;
    [OracleObjectMapping("IOCOST")]
    public decimal IOCOST;
    [OracleObjectMapping("NETWORKCOST")]
    public decimal NETWORKCOST;

    public IOracleCustomType CreateObject()
    {
        return new OdciCost();
    }

    public void FromCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr pointerUdt)
    {
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "CPUCOST", CPUCOST);
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "IOCOST", IOCOST);
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "NETWORKCOST", NETWORKCOST);
        OracleUdt.SetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "INDEXCOSTINFO", INDEXCOSTINFO);
    }

    public void ToCustomObject(OracleConnection connection, IntPtr pointerUdt)
    {
        CPUCOST = (decimal)OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "CPUCOST");
        IOCOST = (decimal)OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "IOCOST");
        NETWORKCOST = (decimal)OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "NETWORKCOST");
        INDEXCOSTINFO = (string)OracleUdt.GetValue(connection, pointerUdt, "INDEXCOSTINFO");
    }

    public bool IsNull
    {
        get { return this._isNull; }
    }

    public static OdciCost Null
    {
        get { return new OdciCost { _isNull = true }; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Incredible how an answer from 2015 helped me 9 years later, when no other online resource, as well as chatbots including GPT-3 and GPT-4 failed to even point me in the right direction.
Thanks for this answer!